# Get the handle of a new GetObject()

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to get the handle from a newly created `GetObject()`. Once I have the handle, then I can control the window's size. How would I get the handle ?

```
On Error GoTo Errorhandler

    Dim SecCheck As Object

    Set SecCheck = GetObject("C:\VICI\" & Right(TxtFile(CurrentProject.Path 
    _ & "\Aux Files\DPAS\DPAS.txt", 1, ""), 6) 
    _ & "\Fleet Management Data Interface.accdb") <---- new object that I want to get the handle from

    SizeNewWindow SecCheck, 0, 0, 1920, 1080 <---- API for resizing windows
```

Comment: For a form I think it's just `UIForm.hWnd`. Maybe `SecCheck.hWnd`? (long)

Comment: If you can set the application, there's a built-in `Application.hWndAccessApp` (if needed).